# LDAP client on Fedora 18

Tags: linux, ldap, fedora

I'm trying to get Fedora 18 to use LDAP for groups and users. I've installed the package `nss_ldap` and run `authconfig-gtk` to configure the appropriate settings. I have verified that the server is up and running, and I can fetch entries from it using `ldapsearch`. However, when I try `getent passwd`, none of the LDAP users are returned. What else do I need to do to get Fedora to query LDAP for users & groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up figuring it out. I'm posting here so it helps future readers!

There are two things to be done. Fedora 18 does not have the proper package dependencies for sssd (which controls authentication and user/group look-up). Therefore, if you are using LDAP, run the command:

```
yum install pam_ldap
```

Additionally, you will need to edit `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`. Under the `[domain/default]` section, add the option `enumerate = True`. See [this link](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sssd.conf) for details on the enumerate option.

Also, if you are using Kerberos for authentication, you will also need to run:

```
yum install pam_krb5
```

After all this is done, you can easily configure sssd with `system-config-authentication`.